# How to avoid ASP.NET timeout on every Visual Studio 2010 Compile

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two projects, one recent and one very old.

When coding for the most recent project (MVC3, EF5, etc), I just build on VS2010 and Update the website on the browser. Everything works fine.

On the older project (not coded by me with WebForms, LINQ2SQL, custom membership) everytime I compile it and update the browser I get redirected to the login page.

Why this happens and how I can find what is causing it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you were using forms auth, I would say you are losing your authenticated session with the site, and its asking you to reestablish that. Since you are using Custom auth, it may not be the same, but sounds it.

Comment: Check how the custom membership works... That should give you the answer